# Help with R packages to use in my spatial discrete choice model

Tags: r, model-selection, spatial, spatial-interaction-model

I am at a loss as to which R package and approach to use for my modeling. The background is: I have a transportation cross-sectional survey dataset combined with many other GIS datasets. I am attempting to determine the effects of household and urban characteristics surrounding each respondent on their choice to drive or take any other form of transportation.

Having read the Bivand book "Applied Spatial Data Analysis", and most of the documentation of the packages listed below, I am still unclear as to whether this should be done as a point pattern model, since I have a point for each location of survey respondents, or whether it is a spatial probit model, etc. Much of the documentation has only function definitions with very little examples of application from start to finish, and I can't make heads or tails of which chapter of Bivand would be the correct one to follow. From this, can anyone point me in the direction of whether I should be using R packages `spatstat, McSpatial, GWmodel, spatialprobit, spdep, sphet, splancs`or some other package? I am also having trouble creating any type of spatial weights matrix other than a binary neighbor weight, but would like to create a Gaussian or some other exponentially declining weighting scheme for spatial dependency. Any help is much appreciated, I am totally stuck!

Comment: [Here is a quick example](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/kj0i5astl9gu440/Inverse_D2_Distance.R?dl=0) of creating a weights matrix that is the inverse of the distance square from a set of point data in R. Sounds to me like spatial probit will do the trick (assuming you have points for all observations, and no two points are at the exact same location). Searching for "spatial discrete choice" may make the net alittle too wide, that includes other models (like conditional logit, where the choice is among many locations, not a set of smaller choices).

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know the terminology I would use to search what to do in case of spots having the same location?  I have multiple observations from the same household (multiple trips) and all households within the same census block were geocoded to the block centroid for privacy reasons.

Comment: That is potentially alittle harder. For an ad-hoc approach you could coerce the spatial weights matrix to accommodate this, by setting pairs that share the same block group to some minimum distance. Another (non-SAR) option is to include non-linear spatial terms in the model (which is more akin to a spatial error model). My older version of the Bivand book has some examples of doing this with `gam` in R IIRC. Best to consult the literature on how others have dealt with this though in your field.